# Duda posición H1 HTML

Tags: html, body

Hola buenas noches estoy empezando a aprender HTML y tengo esta duda porque el H1 va fuera del  Body cuando enrealidad tendria que ir dentro del body?

```html
 <html>
        <head>
              <title>Temporada 7</title>
              <body background="arrow_original.jpg" bgcolor="FFCECB"></body> 
    </head>
    <body>
            <h1>Enlace para ver la temporada 7</h1>
            <p><a  target = "_blank " href ="https://www.amazon.com/-/es/gp/video/detail/B07JFGJVM1/ref=atv_dp_season_select_s7">Temporada 7</p></a>  
            <img src = "t7.jpg" alt= "t7"
            
        
        </body>
        
        
        <h1><i><FONT COLOR="red">Lista de episodios: </FONT></n></h1> <--------- porque va fuera del body?
    </html>
```

Comment: En realidad, todo ese html esta mal formado.. y los navegadores te lo rescatan...

Comment: mal formado? porque esta mal formado?

Comment: ¿Quién lo ha colocado fuera del `body` y por qué? Al final del `body` suele ir el `footer`, donde se suele colocar información fija como el CopyRight, la dirección, etc., pero aún eso es parte del `body` [Para más detalles consulta este artículo de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure).

Comment: hay un tag img sin cierre... hay un tag p y un tag a que estan cerrados al reves, abajo hay un tag n que no cierra ningun tag (deberia ser i para cerrar el tag i)....

Comment: entiendo, hoy recién empeze a estudiar esto y me estoy guiando con el curso de este instructor no se si alguien hizo algún curso con el sabes si explica bien o mal https://www.udemy.com/course/la-web-desde-cero-aprende-diseno-web-con-html5-y-css3/

Answer (score 1):

por favor mirate la pagina de [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) donde encontraras toda esta información basica.

Trata de entender lo que es la estructura basica de HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <p>
   TODO EL CONTENIDO VA DENTRO DE LAS ETIQUETAS DEL BODY ASI QUE ESA ETIQUETA SIMPLEMENTE ESTA MAL.
   <p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Los encabezados y casi todo va adentro del `<body>`, muy probablemente cuando intentes iniciar ese codigo te lo de como correcta, esto se debe a que el navegador lo interpreta, pero esta MAL.
Ademas que cuando empieces a hacer programas mas grandes, seguramente te va a traer errores, pero ese html esta mal escrito (no solo por eso, si te fijas bien por ejemplo, la etiqueta `<img>` tiene que ser cerrada y no esta cerrada.
NO SE PUEDE ESCRIBIR EL `h1` AFUERA DEL `<body>`.
Con respecto a tu pregunta de porque funciona si esta mal escrito, se debe a que el navegador interpeta que el archivo .html es html, esto hace que se estructure dependiente el formato que trae. Y como el lenguaje esta avanzado,los navegadores tambien, sobreentienden que ese `<h1>` va adentro del `<body>` y lo incerta automaticamente.
Pero en realidad esta mal, es una mala práctica hacer esto, y semanticamente incorrecto, lo mismo pasa por ejemplo cuando te olvidas de cerrar un aprentesis o cuadno ya empieces a programar en un lenguaje de programación como por ejemplo, javascript te olvides un ";" el navegador interpeta que en esa linea de codigo tiene que ir ";" y no causa un error, aunque este mal.

Comment: Entiendo pero cuando abro la página web en Chrome me sale como si estuviera dentro porque sucede eso?

Comment: Todos lo que escribes en un documento **index.html** el navegador y la pc ya interpreta que es un archivo **html** o contiene archivos **html**. Esto depende del orden que se escriba y se estructure el formato **html**. Pero para hacer una buena estructura **html**, y como dios manda, es necesario respetar las reglas. Todo lo que escriba y lo que querríamos mostrar, va dentro del **body**...

Comment: Todo el contenido incluido dentro del elemento <body> es parte de una sección. Las secciones en HTML5 pueden ser anidadas. Cada sección puede tener su propia jerarquía de cabeceras. Por lo tanto, incluso una sección anidada puede tener un elemento <h1>.  Consulta aca: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines#defining_headings_in_html5    Pero lo que pasa es que el navegador lo interpeta y sobreentiende que ese h1 va adentro del body, y ahi es donde automaticamente lo inserta donde tendria que ir.

Comment: Cuidado Milena, ese tipo de comentario no hagas en la sección de respuestas. Aquí debes opinar. Ahí debes dar respuestas claras

Comment: Narciso no entiendo, soy relativamente nueva en Stacoverlfow ¿Que hice mal? Perdon, por lo que sea no me di cuenta. ¿Tengo que eliminar la respuesta?

Comment: Ahí donde insertarse el enlace de la documentación. Eso fue una opinión o comentario (como esté de abajo, que también le dijeron lo mismo). Ahí debes ir solo respuestas.

Comment: Con todo esto  creo que Matías B ya entendió que las etiquetas ```h1``` va dentro de la etiqueta ```**body**```

Comment: Ahhh ya entendí!!! Ahi elimine el enlace, disculpa no sabia!!! Gracias...

Comment: No debiste eliminar el enlace, eso fue una guía para la pregunta. Yo no me referí al enlace que insertarse. Todo está bien ahora. Yo solo te decía que ahí no de debe dar opiniones, sino respuestas. Pero ya está bien

Comment: No creo que haya problema al colocar documentación siempre y cuando de un resumen en la respuesta de porque debería revisarla y como solucionar (si es posible) el problema., aunque en lo posible colocar urls con el formato de urls

Comment: Para que sepas qué está bien o mal en una respuesta, lee [answer] :)

Answer (score 0):

Es que el h1 va dentro del body, quien te dijo que va afuera?
Justamente h1 va abajo de titulo/o es un subtitulo o es lo 1ero que queres escribir y le agregas un p luego del h1.
saludos

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]